# JFrame setsize with x by x input is not square

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am playing around with JFrame and when I do this:

```
public class UI extends JFrame {
    public UI() {
        pack();
        setSize(50, 50);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);     
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UI test =new UI();
    }
}
```

The frame is not square, but when I change (50,50) to something larger (500,500) it is square. Can anyone tell my why this is?

Comment: Minimum size enforced by host peer component?

Comment: @trashgod +1 beat me to it...

Comment: It is typically a bad idea to *directly* set the size of a top level container.  The GUI should be packed according to the preferred content size (plus window decorations).  What goes in the `UI` when it becomes useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SetSize(50,50) is very small size for Jframe, JFrame is a root component so at least use proper size for it. It contains title control box and because of it, to get square with small size is difficult. alternative you can use Jwindow for small square size.

Answer (score 1):

around 133x39 is the minimum size of JFrame, "setBounds(100, 100, 133, 40);" will help you. 
To reduce more, should be setUndecorated(true);